# Customizer Color Scheme Not Passing Colors

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I haven't worked on WordPress in years, Customizer is totally new to me and I believe I have messed up getting the default color scheme values and could really use some help. I took an HTML site and built it ontop of the stock TwentySixteen theme for base file structure as well as to tie into some of the newer features (well new to me). I went in changed the `Customizer.php` file the way I needed it for CSS changes, but its not picking up the color scheme options anymore and passing them through, so my theme currently starts with basically no colors. I am continuing to look through it to see what I have messed up but if anyone could point me in a direction to solving this that would be great.

Here is a pastebin of my Customizer.php file.

http://pastebin.com/gmK4KmGX

While normally I would try to offer more details of what I have tried to do to fix it, at this point I am totally lost just pulled up the Codex to start figuring out some of the new things hoping to get a break somewhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: If I manually select colors and save it, it works. Just isn't working with Color Schemes and the default color scheme.

Edit 2: Also noticed its not auto updating the site when editing in Customizer (as in picking new colors), I am totally stuck now and have to be missing something painfully simple. Going to start a bounty on this.

Comment: There's not much we can do from here as you've provided little information. Are you using a child theme?  Do you get colour customisation back if you activate the 2016 theme? Do you have custom CSS that's overriding the dynamic CSS? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just seeing this comment. Not a child theme, just edited right on top of the 2016 theme. I do not have custom CSS overriding the dynamic css. If I manual select colors and click save it works fine just color scheme does not function or apply base colors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to update the array in color-scheme-control.js to reflect your changes in customizer.php and also your array index in customizer.php for `$color_scheme` is wrong, since you've removed the `$wp_customize->remove_control( 'background_color' );` the index 0 is for `page_background_color` not index 1

Below is the changes I made, currently only works for 'Header Background Image' section which applied to .site selector

**color-scheme-control.js**

```
/* global colorScheme, Color */
/**
 * Add a listener to the Color Scheme control to update other color controls to new values/defaults.
 * Also trigger an update of the Color Scheme CSS when a color is changed.
 */

(function(api) {
  var cssTemplate = wp.template('twentysixteen-color-scheme'),
    colorSchemeKeys = [
      'page_background_color',
      'link_color',
      'main_text_color',
      'secondary_text_color'
    ],
    colorSettings = [
      'page_background_color',
      'link_color',
      'main_text_color',
      'secondary_text_color'
    ];

  api.controlConstructor.select = api.Control.extend({
    ready: function() {
      if ('color_scheme' === this.id) {
        this.setting.bind('change', function(value) {
          var colors = colorScheme[value].colors;

          // Update Page Background Color.
          var color = colors[0];
          api('page_background_color').set(color);
          api.control('page_background_color').container.find('.color-picker-hex')
            .data('data-default-color', color)
            .wpColorPicker('defaultColor', color);

          // Update Link Color.
          color = colors[1];
          api('link_color').set(color);
          api.control('link_color').container.find('.color-picker-hex')
            .data('data-default-color', color)
            .wpColorPicker('defaultColor', color);

          // Update Main Text Color.
          color = colors[2];
          api('main_text_color').set(color);
          api.control('main_text_color').container.find('.color-picker-hex')
            .data('data-default-color', color)
            .wpColorPicker('defaultColor', color);

          // Update Secondary Text Color.
          color = colors[3];
          api('secondary_text_color').set(color);
          api.control('secondary_text_color').container.find('.color-picker-hex')
            .data('data-default-color', color)
            .wpColorPicker('defaultColor', color);
        });
      }
    }
  });

  // Generate the CSS for the current Color Scheme.
  function updateCSS() {
    var scheme = api('color_scheme')(),
      css,
      colors = _.object(colorSchemeKeys, colorScheme[scheme].colors);

    // Merge in color scheme overrides.
    _.each(colorSettings, function(setting) {
      colors[setting] = api(setting)();
    });

    // Add additional color.
    // jscs:disable
    colors.border_color = Color(colors.main_text_color).toCSS('rgba', 0.2);
    // jscs:enable

    css = cssTemplate(colors);

    api.previewer.send('update-color-scheme-css', css);
  }

  // Update the CSS whenever a color setting is changed.
  _.each(colorSettings, function(setting) {
    api(setting, function(setting) {
      setting.bind(updateCSS);
    });
  });
})(wp.customize);
```

**customizer.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Twenty Sixteen Customizer functionality
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */

/**
 * Sets up the WordPress core custom header and custom background features.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @see twentysixteen_header_style()
 */
function twentysixteen_custom_header_and_background() {
    $color_scheme             = twentysixteen_get_color_scheme();
    $default_background_color = trim( $color_scheme[0], '#' );
    $default_text_color       = trim( $color_scheme[3], '#' );

    /**
     * Filter the arguments used when adding 'custom-background' support in Twenty Sixteen.
     *
     * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
     *
     * @param array $args {
     *     An array of custom-background support arguments.
     *
     *     @type string $default-color Default color of the background.
     * }
     */
    add_theme_support( 'custom-background', apply_filters( 'twentysixteen_custom_background_args', array(
        'default-color' => $default_background_color,
    ) ) );

    /**
     * Filter the arguments used when adding 'custom-header' support in Twenty Sixteen.
     *
     * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
     *
     * @param array $args {
     *     An array of custom-header support arguments.
     *
     *     @type string $default-text-color Default color of the header text.
     *     @type int      $width            Width in pixels of the custom header image. Default 1200.
     *     @type int      $height           Height in pixels of the custom header image. Default 280.
     *     @type bool     $flex-height      Whether to allow flexible-height header images. Default true.
     *     @type callable $wp-head-callback Callback function used to style the header image and text
     *                                      displayed on the blog.
     * }
     */
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header', apply_filters( 'twentysixteen_custom_header_args', array(
        'default-text-color'     => $default_text_color,
        'width'                  => 1200,
        'height'                 => 280,
        'flex-height'            => true,
        'wp-head-callback'       => 'twentysixteen_header_style',
    ) ) );
}


if ( ! function_exists( 'twentysixteen_header_style' ) ) :
/**
 * Styles the header text displayed on the site.
 *
 * Create your own twentysixteen_header_style() function to override in a child theme.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @see twentysixteen_custom_header_and_background().
 */
function twentysixteen_header_style() {
    // If the header text option is untouched, let's bail.
    if ( display_header_text() ) {
        return;
    }

    // If the header text has been hidden.
    ?>
    <style type="text/css" id="twentysixteen-header-css">
        .site-branding {
            margin: 0 auto 0 0;
        }

        .site-branding .site-title,
        .site-description {
            clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}
endif; // twentysixteen_header_style

/**
 * Adds postMessage support for site title and description for the Customizer.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @param WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize The Customizer object.
 */
function twentysixteen_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $color_scheme = twentysixteen_get_color_scheme();

    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogname' )->transport         = 'postMessage';
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogdescription' )->transport  = 'postMessage';

    if ( isset( $wp_customize->selective_refresh ) ) {
        $wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'blogname', array(
            'selector' => '.site-title a',
            'container_inclusive' => false,
            'render_callback' => 'twentysixteen_customize_partial_blogname',
        ) );
        $wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'blogdescription', array(
            'selector' => '.site-description',
            'container_inclusive' => false,
            'render_callback' => 'twentysixteen_customize_partial_blogdescription',
        ) );
    }

// Remove the core header textcolor control, as it shares the main text color.
$wp_customize->remove_control( 'background_color' );

    // Add color scheme setting and control.
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'color_scheme', array(
        'default'           => 'default',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'twentysixteen_sanitize_color_scheme',
        'transport'         => 'postMessage',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( 'color_scheme', array(
        'label'    => __( 'Base Color Scheme', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'section'  => 'colors',
        'type'     => 'select',
        'choices'  => twentysixteen_get_color_scheme_choices(),
        'priority' => 1,
    ) );


    // Add page background color setting and control.
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'page_background_color', array(
        'default'           => $color_scheme[0],
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
        'transport'         => 'postMessage',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'page_background_color', array(
        'label'       => __( 'Header Background Color', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'section'     => 'colors',
    ) ) );

    // Remove the core header textcolor control, as it shares the main text color.
    $wp_customize->remove_control( 'header_textcolor' );

    // Add link color setting and control.
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'link_color', array(
        'default'           => $color_scheme[1],
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
        'transport'         => 'postMessage',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'link_color', array(
        'label'       => __( 'Header Text Color', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'section'     => 'colors',
    ) ) );

    // Add main text color setting and control.
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'main_text_color', array(
        'default'           => $color_scheme[2],
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
        'transport'         => 'postMessage',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'main_text_color', array(
        'label'       => __( 'Sidebar Left Background Color', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'section'     => 'colors',
    ) ) );

    // Add secondary text color setting and control.
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'secondary_text_color', array(
        'default'           => $color_scheme[3],
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
        'transport'         => 'postMessage',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'secondary_text_color', array(
        'label'       => __( 'Sidebar Right Background Color', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'section'     => 'colors',
    ) ) );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'twentysixteen_customize_register', 11 );

/**
 * Render the site title for the selective refresh partial.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.2
 * @see twentysixteen_customize_register()
 *
 * @return void
 */
function twentysixteen_customize_partial_blogname() {
    bloginfo( 'name' );
}

/**
 * Render the site tagline for the selective refresh partial.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.2
 * @see twentysixteen_customize_register()
 *
 * @return void
 */
function twentysixteen_customize_partial_blogdescription() {
    bloginfo( 'description' );
}

/**
 * Registers color schemes for Twenty Sixteen.
 *
 * Can be filtered with {@see 'twentysixteen_color_schemes'}.
 *
 * The order of colors in a colors array:
 * 1. Main Background Color.
 * 2. Page Background Color.
 * 3. Link Color.
 * 4. Main Text Color.
 * 5. Secondary Text Color.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @return array An associative array of color scheme options.
 */
function twentysixteen_get_color_schemes() {
    /**
     * Filter the color schemes registered for use with Twenty Sixteen.
     *
     * The default schemes include 'default', 'dark', 'gray', 'red', and 'yellow'.
     *
     * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
     *
     * @param array $schemes {
     *     Associative array of color schemes data.
     *
     *     @type array $slug {
     *         Associative array of information for setting up the color scheme.
     *
     *         @type string $label  Color scheme label.
     *         @type array  $colors HEX codes for default colors prepended with a hash symbol ('#').
     *                              Colors are defined in the following order: Main background, page
     *                              background, link, main text, secondary text.
     *     }
     * }
     */
    return apply_filters( 'twentysixteen_color_schemes', array(
        'default' => array(
            'label'  => __( 'Default', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'colors' => array(
                '#ffffff',
                '#ffffff',
                '#007acc',
                '#1a1a1a',
                '#686868',
            ),
        ),
        'dark' => array(
            'label'  => __( 'Dark', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'colors' => array(
                '#262626',
                '#1a1a1a',
                '#9adffd',
                '#e5e5e5',
                '#c1c1c1',
            ),
        ),
        'gray' => array(
            'label'  => __( 'Gray', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'colors' => array(
                '#616a73',
                '#4d545c',
                '#c7c7c7',
                '#f2f2f2',
                '#f2f2f2',
            ),
        ),
        'red' => array(
            'label'  => __( 'Red', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'colors' => array(
                '#ffffff',
                '#ff675f',
                '#640c1f',
                '#402b30',
                '#402b30',
            ),
        ),
        'yellow' => array(
            'label'  => __( 'Yellow', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'colors' => array(
                '#3b3721',
                '#ffef8e',
                '#774e24',
                '#3b3721',
                '#5b4d3e',
            ),
        ),
    ) );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'twentysixteen_get_color_scheme' ) ) :
/**
 * Retrieves the current Twenty Sixteen color scheme.
 *
 * Create your own twentysixteen_get_color_scheme() function to override in a child theme.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @return array An associative array of either the current or default color scheme HEX values.
 */
function twentysixteen_get_color_scheme() {
    $color_scheme_option = get_theme_mod( 'color_scheme', 'default' );
    $color_schemes       = twentysixteen_get_color_schemes();

    if ( array_key_exists( $color_scheme_option, $color_schemes ) ) {
        return $color_schemes[ $color_scheme_option ]['colors'];
    }

    return $color_schemes['default']['colors'];
}
endif; // twentysixteen_get_color_scheme

if ( ! function_exists( 'twentysixteen_get_color_scheme_choices' ) ) :
/**
 * Retrieves an array of color scheme choices registered for Twenty Sixteen.
 *
 * Create your own twentysixteen_get_color_scheme_choices() function to override
 * in a child theme.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @return array Array of color schemes.
 */
function twentysixteen_get_color_scheme_choices() {
    $color_schemes                = twentysixteen_get_color_schemes();
    $color_scheme_control_options = array();

    foreach ( $color_schemes as $color_scheme => $value ) {
        $color_scheme_control_options[ $color_scheme ] = $value['label'];
    }

    return $color_scheme_control_options;
}
endif; // twentysixteen_get_color_scheme_choices


if ( ! function_exists( 'twentysixteen_sanitize_color_scheme' ) ) :
/**
 * Handles sanitization for Twenty Sixteen color schemes.
 *
 * Create your own twentysixteen_sanitize_color_scheme() function to override
 * in a child theme.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @param string $value Color scheme name value.
 * @return string Color scheme name.
 */
function twentysixteen_sanitize_color_scheme( $value ) {
    $color_schemes = twentysixteen_get_color_scheme_choices();

    if ( ! array_key_exists( $value, $color_schemes ) ) {
        return 'default';
    }

    return $value;
}
endif; // twentysixteen_sanitize_color_scheme

/**
 * Enqueues front-end CSS for color scheme.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @see wp_add_inline_style()
 */
function twentysixteen_color_scheme_css() {
    $color_scheme_option = get_theme_mod( 'color_scheme', 'default' );

    // Don't do anything if the default color scheme is selected.
    if ( 'default' === $color_scheme_option ) {
        return;
    }

    $color_scheme = twentysixteen_get_color_scheme();

    // Convert main text hex color to rgba.
    $color_textcolor_rgb = twentysixteen_hex2rgb( $color_scheme[3] );

    // If the rgba values are empty return early.
    if ( empty( $color_textcolor_rgb ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If we get this far, we have a custom color scheme.
    $colors = array(
        'page_background_color' => $color_scheme[0],
        'link_color'            => $color_scheme[1],
        'main_text_color'       => $color_scheme[2],
        'secondary_text_color'  => $color_scheme[3],
        'border_color'          => vsprintf( 'rgba( %1$s, %2$s, %3$s, 0.2)', $color_textcolor_rgb ),

    );

    $color_scheme_css = twentysixteen_get_color_scheme_css( $colors );

    wp_add_inline_style( 'twentysixteen-style', $color_scheme_css );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentysixteen_color_scheme_css' );

/**
 * Binds the JS listener to make Customizer color_scheme control.
 *
 * Passes color scheme data as colorScheme global.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
function twentysixteen_customize_control_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'color-scheme-control', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/color-scheme-control.js', array( 'customize-controls', 'iris', 'underscore', 'wp-util' ), '20160816', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'color-scheme-control', 'colorScheme', twentysixteen_get_color_schemes() );
}
add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'twentysixteen_customize_control_js' );

/**
 * Binds JS handlers to make the Customizer preview reload changes asynchronously.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
function twentysixteen_customize_preview_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentysixteen-customize-preview', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/customize-preview.js', array( 'customize-preview' ), '20160816', true );
}
add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'twentysixteen_customize_preview_js' );

/**
 * Returns CSS for the color schemes.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @param array $colors Color scheme colors.
 * @return string Color scheme CSS.
 */
function twentysixteen_get_color_scheme_css( $colors ) {
    $colors = wp_parse_args( $colors, array(
        'page_background_color' => '',
        'link_color'            => '',
        'main_text_color'       => '',
        'secondary_text_color'  => '',
        'border_color'          => '',
    ) );

    return <<<CSS
    /* Color Scheme */

    /* Background Color */


    /* Page Background Color */
    .site {
        background-color: {$colors['page_background_color']};
    }


CSS;
}


/**
 * Outputs an Underscore template for generating CSS for the color scheme.
 *
 * The template generates the css dynamically for instant display in the
 * Customizer preview.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
function twentysixteen_color_scheme_css_template() {
    $colors = array(
        'page_background_color' => '{{ data.page_background_color }}',
        'link_color'            => '{{ data.link_color }}',
        'main_text_color'       => '{{ data.main_text_color }}',
        'secondary_text_color'  => '{{ data.secondary_text_color }}',
        'border_color'          => '{{ data.border_color }}',
    );
    ?>
    <script type="text/html" id="tmpl-twentysixteen-color-scheme">
        <?php echo twentysixteen_get_color_scheme_css( $colors ); ?>
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'customize_controls_print_footer_scripts', 'twentysixteen_color_scheme_css_template' );

/**
 * Enqueues front-end CSS for the page background color.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @see wp_add_inline_style()
 */
function twentysixteen_page_background_color_css() {
    $color_scheme          = twentysixteen_get_color_scheme();
    $default_color         = $color_scheme[0];
    $page_background_color = get_theme_mod( 'page_background_color', $default_color );

    // Don't do anything if the current color is the default.
    if ( $page_background_color === $default_color ) {
        return;
    }

    $css = '
        /* Custom Header Background Color */
        .site {
            background-color: %1$s;
        }
        .ui-bar-a {
            background-color: %1$s;
        }

    ';

    wp_add_inline_style( 'twentysixteen-style', sprintf( $css, $page_background_color ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentysixteen_page_background_color_css', 11 );

/**
 * Enqueues front-end CSS for the link color.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @see wp_add_inline_style()
 */
function twentysixteen_link_color_css() {
    $color_scheme    = twentysixteen_get_color_scheme();
    $default_color   = $color_scheme[2];
    $link_color = get_theme_mod( 'link_color', $default_color );

    // Don't do anything if the current color is the default.
    if ( $link_color === $default_color ) {
        return;
    }

    $css = '
        /* Custom Header Text Color */

        [data-role=header] .header-title {
             color: %1$s;
         }

         [data-role=panel][data-theme=d] .widget * {
             color: %1$s;
         }

         [data-role=panel][data-theme=d] ul li a {
         color: %1$s !important;
         }
    ';

    wp_add_inline_style( 'twentysixteen-style', sprintf( $css, $link_color ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentysixteen_link_color_css', 11 );

/**
 * Enqueues front-end CSS for the main text color.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @see wp_add_inline_style()
 */
function twentysixteen_main_text_color_css() {
    $color_scheme    = twentysixteen_get_color_scheme();
    $default_color   = $color_scheme[3];
    $main_text_color = get_theme_mod( 'main_text_color', $default_color );

    // Don't do anything if the current color is the default.
    if ( $main_text_color === $default_color ) {
        return;
    }

    // Convert main text hex color to rgba.
    $main_text_color_rgb = twentysixteen_hex2rgb( $main_text_color );

    // If the rgba values are empty return early.
    if ( empty( $main_text_color_rgb ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If we get this far, we have a custom color scheme.
    $border_color = vsprintf( 'rgba( %1$s, %2$s, %3$s, 0.2)', $main_text_color_rgb );

    $css = '

    /* Custom Sidebar Left Background Color */

    [data-role=panel][data-theme=a] {
        background: %1$s;
        border-right: 1px solid %1$s;
    }  

    ';

    wp_add_inline_style( 'twentysixteen-style', sprintf( $css, $main_text_color, $border_color ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentysixteen_main_text_color_css', 11 );

/**
 * Enqueues front-end CSS for the secondary text color.
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @see wp_add_inline_style()
 */
function twentysixteen_secondary_text_color_css() {
    $color_scheme    = twentysixteen_get_color_scheme();
    $default_color   = $color_scheme[4];
    $secondary_text_color = get_theme_mod( 'secondary_text_color', $default_color );

    // Don't do anything if the current color is the default.
    if ( $secondary_text_color === $default_color ) {
        return;
    }

    $css = '
        /* Custom Sidebar Right Background Color */

    .ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-open.ui-panel-position-right.ui-panel-display-overlay, .ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-open.ui-panel-position-right.ui-panel-display-push {
        background: %1$s;
    }

    .ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-position-right.ui-panel-display-overlay, .ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-position-right.ui-panel-display-push {
        background: %1$s;
    }

    ';

    wp_add_inline_style( 'twentysixteen-style', sprintf( $css, $secondary_text_color ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentysixteen_secondary_text_color_css', 11 );
```

Comment: Thank you Slashshap this work except for applying the default color scheme when a new installation occurs, not sure if it would matter that it is WordPress Multisite but if I create a new site and this theme is set as the theme WordPress selects as default, after site creation it is currently passing no colors through even though it has the default selected, which then makes everything display white. Any ideas?

Comment: Also to explain a bit more it works if I go in and manually select my color changes just does not apply the default that are in the arrays default option, unless I make a change then go back and select default then at that point it would apply the default color scheme.